# Azure AD, unable to set AdditionalData against Invitation

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I am using the GraphServiceClient to create invitation to add Guest in Azure Ad and I need to add AdditionalData in the invitation.

```
var invitation = new Microsoft.Graph.Invitation
{
     InvitedUserDisplayName = "John Doe",
     InvitedUserEmailAddress = "john.doe@test.com",
     InviteRedirectUrl = "https://test.com",
     SendInvitationMessage = false,
     AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
     {
      {"JobTitle", "Doctor"},
      {"UsageLocation", "FR"}
     }
};

await graphClient.Invitations
      .Request()
      .AddAsync(invitation);
```

John Doe is created as Guest in Azure Ad, but JobTitle and UsageLocation are null.
Is it possible to add AdditionalData on invitation or only on user ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are trying to invite guest user along with `AdditionalData` using `Microsoft Graph API SDK`.

You could try this way:

```
            InvitedUserMessageInfo info = new InvitedUserMessageInfo();
            object obj = new object();
            obj = "Testing Another Additional Data";

            var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            dict.Add("Data1", obj);
            dict.Add("Data2", obj);
            info.AdditionalData = dict;
            

     

            var invitation = new Invitation
            {
                InvitedUserEmailAddress = "testemail@outlook.com",
                InviteRedirectUrl = "https://yourapplicationurl.com",
                InvitedUserMessageInfo = info
            };

                 await _graphServiceClient.Invitations
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(invitation);
```

> **Note:** Make sure you have required permission on your `Tenant` as specified on [Microsoft official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions)

Hope it will help. Let me know if you have any further concern.

Comment: Hi Farid, thank you for your help. I try your code but the additional data are null in Azure Ad for my guest.

Comment: Did you checked while you are sending request wether it contains that data?

Comment: In agreement with the Azure AD administrator, I will create users rather than invitations. The first tests are ok and I can populate the desired properties.
Thank you for your help and your time.